# Get oracle rowid in ODP.net using EF 5

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I'm actually using ODP.net tools with VS2015 to access a database with Oracle.

IE. using Oracle SQL Developer

`select rowid from employees`

It returns

[image: Captura.png]

Is there any way to get the oracle 'rowid' field using Entity Framework 5?

Answer (score 1):

ROWID basically allows you to have two rows with the exact same data. While, you typically want your Primary Key to be a little more meaningful than a RowID, it is just a simple way of automatically ensuring uniqueness between rows.ROWID does not persist across a database EXPORT and IMPORT cycle. you should NEVER store a rowid in your tables as a key value.

You can use procedure for this.

Comment: Came to this late, but the answer doesn't answer the asked question.